# Ring isomorphic and irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let z = x+yi ∈ C, where z ̅=x-yi.

a) Show that the map f: C →C, where f(z)=z ̅ is a ring isomorphic
b) Give an example of an irreducible polynomial of degree two in R[X]

a) I’m not completely sure how to do this.
b) X^2 +1 is an an irreducible polynomial of degree two in R[X]
   Because(x+1)(x-1)=x^2+1

Comment: For b) $(x+1)(x-1)\neq x^2+1$, but yes, $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: yes, you are right, its x^2 - 1 ofcourse.
But how do I show that x^2+1 is irreducible over ℝ?

Comment: A polynomial of degree $2$ over a field $K$ is irreducible if and only if it has a root in $K$. Does $x^2+1$ have a root in $\mathbb{R}$?